# How to cut part of the string within a word of a random number of labels inside a list?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is a simple example of what I have:

```
<div>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <a href="">
           <label>Example1 something I don't want</label>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="">
           <label>Example2 something I don't want</label>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="">
           <label>Example3 something I don't want</label>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="">
           <label>Example4 something I don't want</label>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="">
           <label>Example5 something I don't want</label>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

The structure of code I have is this one. This is generated automatically, so In this `<div>` some times there are more `<li>` tags(with it's content inside) or less depending on what data it gets from database.

What I want to do is with javascript and jquery get the list and cut the content of the labels from the word 'something' till the end of it so it does not appear.

**The word is always de same** (something), so what I want to do is read that word and cut it out with the rest of text it comes behind it.

The **result** should be this:

```
    <div>
       <ul>
          <li>
             <a href="">
               <label>Example1</label>
             </a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="">
               <label>Example2</label>
             </a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="">
               <label>Example3</label>
             </a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="">
               <label>Example4</label>
             </a>
          </li>
          <li>
             <a href="">
               <label>Example5</label>
             </a>
          </li>
       </ul>
    </div>
```

I hope I explained myself right.

If you have any questions ask me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `substr()`:

```js
var cutWord = 'something';
$('ul li').each(function(){
  var text = $(this).find('label').text();
  var newText = text.substr(0, text.indexOf(cutWord)).trim();
  $(this).find('label').text(newText);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <a href="">
           <label>Example1 something I don't want</label>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="">
           <label>Example2 something I don't want</label>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="">
           <label>Example3 something I don't want</label>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="">
           <label>Example4 something I don't want</label>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="">
           <label>Example5 something I don't want</label>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! This is what I wanted, Thanks very much! :D It works very well!

Comment: @ArrozConTé glad to help :)

Answer (score 2):

Since there is a space behind them you can split the string on space.

```js
$('label').each(function(){
   var splitted = $(this).text().split(" ");
   $(this).text(splitted[0]);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
   <ul>
      <li>
         <a href="">
           <label>Example1 something I don't want</label>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="">
           <label>Example2 something I don't want</label>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="">
           <label>Example3 something I don't want</label>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="">
           <label>Example4 something I don't want</label>
         </a>
      </li>
      <li>
         <a href="">
           <label>Example5 something I don't want</label>
         </a>
      </li>
   </ul>
</div>
```